# How does extern work in c++?

Tags: c++, syntax, extern

This is from the `<iostream>`:

```
namespace std 
{
  extern istream cin;       ///< Linked to standard input
  extern ostream cout;  
...
```

It seems by using `extern` the data types defined in other namespaces will just be available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`extern` is used to refer to a variable defined in a different compilation unit (for now, you can think of a compilation unit as a .cpp file).  The statements in your example *declare* rather than *define* `cin` and `cout`.  It is telling the compiler that the definition of these objects is found in another compilation unit (where they are **not** declared as `extern`).

Comment: But I don't find anywhere that define `cin`,only `istream` is defined in `<iosfwd>`

Comment: `cin` is an object of type `istream`.  `istream` is the class (in this case, template class) definition.  `cin` is an instance of the `istream` class.  The "definition" I refer to in my answer is the definition of `cin`, not `istream`.  You need to look up the meaning of *definition* vs. *declaraion*.  The statements in your examples are *declarations*.

Comment: The *definition* of the `cin` variable is most likely in a run-time library.  You won't find it in the standard library header files.

Comment: @STingRaySC ,is there a trick to find where it's actually defined?

Comment: @symfony: No. It's defined in code that's already been compiled into a library that you will link your code with.  In general, a variable referred to by an `extern` declaration can be defined in **any** compilation unit that is made available to the linker (in the form of a compiled object file).

Answer (score 9):

`extern` means "these variables are defined in some other compilation unit (.cpp or .lib file)"

In this case, you `#include <iostream>` into your .cpp file, and because `cin` and `cout` are declared as `extern`, the compiler will let you use them without complaining. Then, when the linker runs, it looks up all of the `extern` variables and sorts it all out.

Comment: Does it mean `istream` or `cin` is defined in some other unit in the case of `extern istream cin;`?

Comment: It means `cin` is. This is not the same thing as the *class definition*, which in this case, is in `iostream`.  The *class definition* must always be available in a compilation unit to use objects of that class' type (this is why class definitions are put into *header* files).

Comment: `cin` and `cout` are global variables. In C++, a global variable must be declare in one and only one .cpp file (with some exceptions). So if you just said `istream cin` then the linker would complain when you go to link two files which both declare the variable because it wouldn't know which one to use. So by declaring all but one of them as `extern`, you tell the linker to use the non-`extern` as the "real" one, and the `extern` ones just say "this variable is declared in some other .cpp file".

Comment: the distinction between *declare* and *define* is critical to understanding this.  Please get it right!  They are not synonymous.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is an explicit way to say `cin` and `cout` are declared without actually defining them.

Answer (score 0):

The **extern** keyword tells the compiler that a variable is declared in another source(i.e outside the current scope). The linker then finds this actual declaration and sets up the **extern** variable to point to the correct location.

variables declared by **extern** statements will not have any space allocated for them, as they should be properly defined elsewhere. If a variable is declared **extern**, and the linker finds no actual declaration of it, it will show error.

Eg. **extern** int i;

//this declares that there is a variable named i of type int, defined somewhere in the program.

Answer (score 0):

Some answers say here that extern means that variable is defined in other compilation unit. Then, following should not compile as no other compilation unit or file is provided to compiler.

```
extern int a;
int main(){
    std::cout<<a<<std::endl;    //Prints 3
}
int a=3;
```

So, I think extern is explicitly used to separate the declaration and definition in case of variable as stated in one of answer. I think it is useless in case of functions.