# Can you explain what extern means and some other things?

Tags: c++, c

I know that extern C means the function should be compiled in C style however what does just extern function_datatype functionname mean?

```
extern void sharelog(const char *rem_host, const char *username,
         const char *, const char *,
         const char *, const char *);
```

What does extern without "C" mean?

Also, in almost every program's header files i see something along the lines of

```
void sharelog(const char *rem_host, const char *username,
         const char *, const char *,
         const char *, const char *);
```

Why declare the function again if it's been done in the .c/.cpp file?
It's also sometimes declared without it's argument just

```
int Function;
```

Also, some functions can be written like this:

```
int CSomething::Somefunction() const
```

Why add const after the function?

I've also stumbled across functions which have these mysterious dots

```
void function(int prio, const char *fmt, ...)
```

There were a lot of other things i also wanted to ask, however it seems i already asked enough.
I know some of you will probably say to go learn C/C++, however believe me, these stuff are not discussed for beginners.

Comment: You really should split this up into multiple questions, it's quite annoying to try to answer a n-way question.

Comment: And the topics of your questions are only remotely related. They really should be separate questions.

Comment: @unwind: Also, you cannot close it as duplicates of 4 other questions.

Comment: Better you put each of them as individual questions...

Comment: I've already asked though, no need to make another question since it's been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `extern` without `"C"` comes from pre-C++ times when you needed a way to tell the C compiler that a function is available "somewhere" and it should allow the linker to figure it out.

The declaration with `extern` allowed the compiler to add the function to the list of known names even if it couldn't resolve the address.

Answer (score 6):

1. [How does extern work in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513108/how-does-extern-work-in-c)
2. [Why does C++ need a separate header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305947/why-does-c-need-a-separate-header-file)
3. [const CFoo &bar() const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742084/const-cfoo-bar-const) and [What's the difference between a const member function and a non-const member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066863/whats-the-difference-between-a-const-member-function-and-a-non-const-member-func)
4. [What's the correct term for the '...' token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937454/correct-term-for)